# How to clear $T$ from the formula $vf = vp ( 1 + t \times i )$?

Tags: change-of-variable

Given the formula $vf = vp ( 1 + t \times i )$, I would like to clear $t$.

I would like to know what is the steps to do this. I have issues with formulas and don't understand. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear $t$"? Do you mean solve for $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's elementary algebra.
Given

$$ 
v_f = v_p(1 + it)
$$

you get
$$
\frac{v_f}{v_p} = 1 + it,
$$
then
$$
\frac{v_f}{v_p} -1 = it 
$$
so
$$
t = \frac{1}{i}\left( \frac{v_f}{v_p} -1 \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you so much